# Get Azure Data Factory logs

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I need to retrieve azure data factory pipelines execution logs. I've tried with Web Acticity by using the following request:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/{runId}?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Unfortunatelly I have the following error:

```
Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - 'NotFound', message - 'The requested resource does not exist on the server. Please verify the request server and retry'
```

Should I set some additionall configuration to be able to retrieve these logs?

Comment: If the specified runid or the resource doesn't exist you see that error. Recheck if all the resource name and values are correct spelling

Comment: For sure I replace the values. As runId I insert system parameter (Pipeline Run Id). The url works for pipeline details ...../pipelines/pipeline1?api-version=2018-06-01 but it does not work for pipeline run.

Comment: Can you share some snip of your setup for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of pipeline runs using  [Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory)

Next, you can Get a pipeline run by its run ID.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/{runId}?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Here is a sample URL:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-XXXX-XXX-XXXXX-2n83a074t23f/resourceGroups/resource-grp/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/ktestadf/pipelineruns/0bdaba11-47b7-4885-9796-5801b4bb856a?api-version=2018-06-01
```

If you are constructing URL dynamically, using Pipeline RunID system variable, you can using string interpolation method. Notice **@{pipeline().RunId}** in place of **{runId}**.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-2n83a074t23f/resourceGroups/resource-grp/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/ktestadf/pipelineruns/@{pipeline().RunId}?api-version=2018-06-01
```

> **Note:** You would have to Trigger run and not debug, since this will create pipeline. Make sure you have published all before trigering
> run, debug can take the changes but pipeline run needs the changes be
> published.

[image]

And here is a simple WebActivity setup:

[image]

Input

```
{
    "url": " https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/b83c1td3-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-2b83a074c13f/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/ktestadf/pipelineruns/0bdaba11-47b7-4885-9796-5801b4bb856a?api-version=2018-06-01 ",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "authentication": {
        "type": "MSI",
        "resource": " https://management.azure.com/  "
    }
}
```

[image]

You can get a pipeline run ID from here manually to test.

[image]

I did repro before posting this and the only reason this error pops is cause any value you provided is wrong or does not already exist (in case of pipeline run id)

[image]

Comment: Are you triggering run or testing in debug ? please check updated note

Comment: I use debug for testing

Comment: Please trigger run, cause only then will you get the pipeline run id in system variable

Comment: Awesome! glad could be of help 